# VSCode debugger break point doesn't for django project

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I recently shifted to mac M1 from ubuntu and I have installed VS code and tried to debug the project but it didn't stop at any breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You must start  the sever before the debugger will go to the break-point. Once you press run wait until it is finished

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django